# What is the value of esp after a function returns?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm

In C / x86, when returning from a function we typically:

1. `pop ebp` to restore the previous function's frame pointer
2. `ret` which (as I understand) contains an implicit `pop eip` so that the calling function can continue to execute from the return address

At this point, what can I expect esp to contain? Will it be a pointer to whatever was directly above the return address, or is the value of esp also implicitly changed by `ret` ?

Thanks :)

Comment: In the CDECL calling convention, `esp` will now point to the last parameter pushed onto the stack before the call.

Comment: For further questions like this, you might want to read the manual which contains very detailed explanations of what each instruction does.

Comment: @CodyGray: `ret` does affect esp: it pops the return address like the OP said.  The correct statement is that a call/return pair don't affect the stack (assuming a calling convention where the caller pops the args, instead of the callee using `ret imm16`)

Comment: Ugh, typo! meant to say *does*. Thanks @Peter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Will it be a pointer to whatever was directly above the return address, or is the value of esp also implicitly changed by ret ?

There are two forms of `ret`: just `ret` and `ret N`. The first form simply pops eip (which as usual means both "take eip and add esp,4") from stack and continues execution, so esp points at the last parameter pushed when calling the function - this means that caller must deal with this by subsequent `add esp, N`.

`ret N` means that after popping eip, esp is added by value N in the same instruction, so there's no need for the caller to do that. The drawback is that you can't use variable number of args, because 'N' can only be constant value.

Answer (score 2):

After a `ret`, `esp` should contain the same value it had right before the corresponding `call` if no shenanigans happened in between. The `call` instruction pushes the return value on the stack, the `ret` instruction pops it off. So yes, your intuition is correct.

Answer (score 1):

After the ret, sp should be the same as it was at the point where the call to the function occured.

So it would point to whatever was last pushed to the stack.